# PHP: Replace words within string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have following string:

```
@c24-blue: #005ea8; @c24-green: #737948;
```

Now i want to replace the definition of @c24-green to #fff.

I have tried it over:

```
$string = '@c24-blue: #005ea8; @c24-green: #737948;';
$string = preg_replace('/([@c24-green:]) (.*);/', '$1' . ' #fff;', $string);
```

The result should be:

```
@c24-blue: #005ea8; @c24-green: #fff;
```

Is there a solution to get this working?

Regards,
Kai

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(@c24-green:)[^;]+/', '$1 #fff', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your string `"@c24-green:"` from character class, following should work..

```
(@c24-green:) (.*);
 ^         ^

$string = preg_replace('/(@c24-green:) (.*);/', '$1' . ' #fff;', $string);
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sW3qN8/1)

**Edit:** If you want to make it generic.. you can use the following:

```
(@[^:]*:) ([^;]*);
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sW3qN8/2)

Comment: For c24-green it works, but how have i to define the regex if it should also work for c24-blue? Than it returns only @c24-blue: #fff;

Comment: You mean you want to make it generic or just for `c24-green` and `c24-blue`?

Comment: At least it should be generic.